# Inheritance MS SQL on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have this diagram:**

[image: Diagram[1]]

Where both Professional and Patient inherit from the table user.

The user id id a PK.
Professional.id and Patient.id are primary keys of their tables.
They're also FK that reference user.id.

The question here is why when I do select * from Professional I don't get the inerited column from the table User?.

I know I can join them but I thought the concept of inheritance was supposed to share the fiels from the table User in this case to the tables Professional and Patient.

Comment: Your diagram is showing *join* relationships between tables.  This is not the same as "inheritance".  You may be confused by what an entity-relationship diagram is showing.

Comment: What should I fix in the diagram Gordon Linoff?
I had some reading about the inheritance and the way to do inheritance was described just like I did on the diagram :/. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a "one-of" relationship.  Not all E-R diagramming tools support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - SQL Server is not an OODBMS. Though you logically have defined a type of inheritance, the engine does not provide any direct support for including the inherited attributes in the child "class". The query "select * from table" will only include columns from the specified table. **You** the developer must write your queries to select the tables and columns your statement needs.

Comment: Thanks so I'll have to do the Joins myself Cheers,